# Why tape.gradient returns all none in my Sequential model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient, sequential

I have to compute the gradients of this model:

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu',input_dim=12))
model.add(Dense(60, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='softmax'))
opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=opt)

model_q=Sequential()
model_q.add(Dense(40, activation='relu',input_dim=15))
model_q.add(Dense(60, activation='relu'))
model_q.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))
opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)
model_q.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=opt)

x=np.random.random(12)
x2=model.predict(x.reshape(-1,12))
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            value = model_q([tf.convert_to_tensor(np.append(x,x2).reshape(-1,15))])
            loss = -tf.reduce_mean(value)
grad = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, model.trainable_variables))
```

but grad returns all none so opt can't apply gradients to the model. Why is this happening? I know it's quite a strange loss but it's the thing I would like to compute

Comment: You are trying to update `model`, however you are predicting with `model_q`. During backpropagation the variables of `model` do no contribute to the loss from `model_q`, so the gradients are zero. (The derivative wrt. variables of `model` is zero, because the output of `model_q` is not a function of the variables of `model`.) Always keep in mind how backprop works, when constructing custom loss functions etc.!

Comment: yes but I compute model_q with x and x2: the last one is derived from "model", so the value I get should be a function of the variables of model. I think there is an issue with the combination of numpy and tf

Comment: `model` is not recorded (/watched) by the tape. I modified your code a bit, check my answer and see if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `model` is not being recorded by the tape. You have to put the computations into the context of the tape if you want to get gradients.

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu',input_dim=12))
model.add(Dense(60, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(units=3, activation='softmax'))
opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)

model_q=Sequential()
model_q.add(Dense(40, activation='relu',input_dim=15))
model_q.add(Dense(60, activation='relu'))
model_q.add(Dense(units=1, activation='linear'))
opt=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001)

x=np.random.random(12).reshape(-1,12)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  x2 = model([x])
  value = model_q([tf.concat((x,x2), -1)])
  loss = -tf.reduce_mean(value)
grad = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, model.trainable_variables))
```